# eclipse import project from tomcat webapp

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

i have a project in tomcat,and use `startup` to set up it.

[image]

i want to import it into eclipse in order to debug it,and then i try to import project like this:

[image]

it displays no project found, maybe it does not have .project file

how could i import it correctly and conviently? there are only class in web-inf,so how could copy it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this, however...
Perhaps, the simplest way to do this is the following:

- Download Eclipse Java EE
- Create a Dynamic Web project
- Copy the contents of your webapp (or war) to the WebContent folder

If the project contains Java sources andyou have access to them add them (including the package structure) to the src folder.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

1. Create new Dymanic Web Project in Eclipse
2. Right click -> Import -> General -> File system, on this project.
3. Choose source directory.

And check Java Build Path in your project to be sure your Libraries correctly loaded.